# Setting the weights for an edge

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to build a graph with node labels and weighted edges. However I struggle finding a correct way to do so. Here is my simplified attempt:

```
CompleteGraph[{2,3},VertexLabels->Automatic,EdgeWeight->{#->0.5}]
EdgeList[%]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph] // MatrixForm
```

The adjacency matrix is still filled with 0 and 1, I am not sure to understand why.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Edgweight-> {_->w,0.5} not {#->0.5}

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to set edge weights on an existing graph, or when creating a new graph. See [`EdgeWeight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeWeight.html) for details.

Specify the weights in the same order as edges. This is usually the fastest, but you must know the edge ordering, and you must make sure that the weight list has the same length as the number of edges.

```
CompleteGraph[{2,3}, EdgeWeight -> Range[6]]
```

Specify the weight for specific edges.

```
CompleteGraph[{2, 3}, EdgeWeight -> {2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 5}]
```

Note that using `<->` instead of `\[UndirectedEdge]`, meaning `TwoWayRule`, does not currently work in this context.

Edges for which you did not specify a weight will get weight `1`. Note that this happens only with certain specific edge properties, such as `EdgeWeight` or `EdgeCost`, but not custom properties.

You can specify your own default as well. For example, let's use `3`:

```
CompleteGraph[{2, 3}, EdgeWeight -> {3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 5}]
```

We can also use a pattern to select edges:

```
CompleteGraph[{2, 3}, EdgeWeight -> {_ -> 5}]
```

This will be much slower than specifying a weight list though.

There are yet other methods with [`AnnotationValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnnotationValue.html) and [`Annotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotate.html), look them up.

My [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) contains many helpful tools for dealing with edge weights. IMO it is not exaggeration to say that it is indispensable for practical work with weighted graphs.

The philosophy of this package is to always work with lists of weights (or property values), which makes it easier to implement performant operations. The `k`th element of the weight vector belongs to the `k`th edge.

To get the weight vector, you can use `IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]`:

```
In[417]:= 
Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> {3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 5}] // IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]

Out[417]= {3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3}
```

To remove weights, use `IGUnweighted`.

To transform weights, e.g. square each one, use `IGEdgeMap`:

```
In[418]:= 
Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> {3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 5}] // IGEdgeMap[#^2 &, EdgeWeight] // IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]

Out[418]= {9, 9, 9, 25, 9, 9}
```

`IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` and `IGWeightedAdjacencyMatrix` are much more convenient that `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` and `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` because they are actually consistent with each other: both use zero to represent missing edges, and give you the opportunity to choose another value for this purpose. In contrast, `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` uses zero while `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` uses `Infinity`, so you can't use them together conveniently.

There is `IGWeightedUndirectedGraph` and `IGWeightedSimpleGraph` which let you choose how to combine the weights of reciprocal or parallel edges. `UndirectedGraph` and `SimpleGraph` threw away weights until recently, and do not allow specifying a combiner even in the current version.